# Do the recent findings of an ape-like creature in Europe with human-like teeth change the Out of Africa narrative?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, human-genetics, human-evolution

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/science/2017/05/22/europe-birthplace-mankind-not-africa-scientists-find/

Two fossils of an ape with human-like teeth were discovered in Greece, and Bulgaria, and they are about 7.2 million years old.

Does this change the narrative of the 'Out of Africa' theory?

Have scientists in the relevant fields commented on this yet?

Comment: Of course every researcher wants to find something exciting and new. As the linked Telegraph article identifies their fossiles as the oldest hominins ever found, arguing that the lineages between pre-humans and chimpanzees therefore split in Europe, with pre-humans then migrating back to Africa to be consistent with other evidence.

Answer (score 6):

> Does this change the narrative of the Out of Africa theory?

Not at all since the Out-Of-Africa hypothesis is about the African origin of all **modern humans** (*Homo sapiens*), i.e. that the species originated in Africa and then spread over the rest of the world. It is not about where possible, early ancestors may have originated. The ape from the article, *[Graecopithecus freybergi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graecopithecus)* is claimed to be one of the oldest Hominines<sup>a</sup>, but that does not change the claim of the Out-Of-Africa hypothesis.

**Reference**

<sup>a</sup> Fuss, Jochen, et al. "Potential hominin affinities of Graecopithecus from the Late Miocene of Europe." PloS one 12.5 (2017): e0177127. https://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0177127